# How to mark the maven build status as Fail if there are skipped test in build result summary?

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

When I am running my TestNG test cases with the help of the maven surefire plugin, it skips a few test cases. And at the end my result summary comes like this:

```
Tests run: 26, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 15
```

When we see the overall build status, it shows:

```
SUCCESS
```

As there are tests skipped, we want to make the build status a failure.
How can we achieve it?

maven surefire plugin details:

```
maven-surefire-plugin : 2.19.1
```

Comment: First use more recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (not related) and check why tests skipped... A skipped test is not counted as a failing test..

Comment: Behavior is the same with the latest version too. Test skip reason I know, I just need to set the build as Unstable/Fail if there is any skipped test.

Comment: Than change your test to fail... why is it skipped? Can you show an example of that.. ? A skipped tests means you know the reason ????